# Exporting customer data from xtcmodified to Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

I searched the net but found no real solution. Is there an easy way to export xtcmodified customer data into Magento?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First: You will get a more specific answer here, if you clarify some details of your question. Giving us some information about your xtcmodified customer data and how it looks like will give us a better idea about your problem.

By default, you can import customer data in the formats of MS Excel XML or CSV / Tab separated.

Have a look at the settings and profiles in a standard Magento installation:

```
System > Import/Export > Import
```

You can also define Dataflow Profiles for the import and export there including value delimiters, values enclosing characters.

The standard customer export in Magento CE 1.9.1.0 looks like this:

```
email,_website,_store,confirmation,created_at,created_in,disable_auto_group_change,dob,firstname,gender,group_id,lastname,middlename,password_hash,prefix,rp_token,rp_token_created_at,store_id,suffix,taxvat,website_id,password,_address_city,_address_company,_address_country_id,_address_fax,_address_firstname,_address_lastname,_address_middlename,_address_postcode,_address_prefix,_address_region,_address_street,_address_suffix,_address_telephone,_address_vat_id,_address_default_billing_,_address_default_shipping_
email@domain.com,base,default,,"2015-02-17 00:06:00","Default Store View",0,,John,,1,Doe,,password,,,,1,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

If you transform your xtcmodified data into a CSV like this, you can import it into Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to @anna-völkl's answer: You can get a customer export module for modified eCommerce in their [forum](http://www.modified-shop.org/forum/index.php?topic=6003.0). You can probably edit the resulting file to match Magento's format presented by Anna and import it.